# the select performance issue on mysql 8.0

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-8.0

I have met a performance issue for the sql below.

```
select a.id, a.name, a.chinese_name, turnover, group_concat(b.branch) as branch, 
       group_concat(b.type_of_service) as service 
 from kn_supplier a join kn_supplier_service b
   on a.id = b.supplier_id
group by a.name
```

It runs around 13 seconds on machine A, but almost 2 seconds on machine B. The question is both machine A and machine B have the same enviroment with MySQL 8.0. The schema, the tables, the index are all the same. Why it has so many big difference? Is there any trick on MySQL 8.0 I forgot to set?  Note, the sql runs on local server.

I tried to profile both machines, 
Machine A
[image]

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROFILING WHERE QUERY_ID=7;
+----------+-----+--------------------------------+-----------+-----------+------------+-------------------+---------------------+--------------+---------------+---------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------+--------------------------------+----------------------+-------------+
| QUERY_ID | SEQ | STATE                          | DURATION  | CPU_USER  | CPU_SYSTEM | CONTEXT_VOLUNTARY | CONTEXT_INVOLUNTARY | BLOCK_OPS_IN | BLOCK_OPS_OUT | MESSAGES_SENT | MESSAGES_RECEIVED | PAGE_FAULTS_MAJOR | PAGE_FAULTS_MINOR | SWAPS | SOURCE_FUNCTION                | SOURCE_FILE          | SOURCE_LINE |
+----------+-----+--------------------------------+-----------+-----------+------------+-------------------+---------------------+--------------+---------------+---------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------+--------------------------------+----------------------+-------------+
|        7 |   2 | starting                       |  0.000260 |  0.000000 |   0.000000 |              NULL |                NULL |         NULL |          NULL |          NULL |              NULL |              NULL |              NULL |  NULL | NULL                           | NULL                 |        NULL |
|        7 |   3 | Executing hook on transaction  |  0.000010 |  0.000000 |   0.000000 |              NULL |                NULL |         NULL |          NULL |          NULL |              NULL |              NULL |              NULL |  NULL | launch_hook_trans_begin        | rpl_handler.cc       |        1107 |
|        7 |   4 | starting                       |  0.000017 |  0.000000 |   0.000000 |              NULL |                NULL |         NULL |          NULL |          NULL |              NULL |              NULL |              NULL |  NULL | launch_hook_trans_begin        | rpl_handler.cc       |        1109 |
|        7 |   5 | checking permissions           |  0.000009 |  0.000000 |   0.000000 |              NULL |                NULL |         NULL |          NULL |          NULL |              NULL |              NULL |              NULL |  NULL | check_access                   | sql_authorization.cc |        2203 |
|        7 |   6 | checking permissions           |  0.000011 |  0.000000 |   0.000000 |              NULL |                NULL |         NULL |          NULL |          NULL |              NULL |              NULL |              NULL |  NULL | check_access                   | sql_authorization.cc |        2203 |
|        7 |   7 | Opening tables                 |  0.000944 |  0.000000 |   0.000000 |              NULL |                NULL |         NULL |          NULL |          NULL |              NULL |              NULL |              NULL |  NULL | open_tables                    | sql_base.cc          |        5590 |
|        7 |   8 | init                           |  0.000018 |  0.000000 |   0.000000 |              NULL |                NULL |         NULL |          NULL |          NULL |              NULL |              NULL |              NULL |  NULL | Sql_cmd_dml::execute           | sql_select.cc        |         662 |
|        7 |   9 | System lock                    |  0.000025 |  0.000000 |   0.000000 |              NULL |                NULL |         NULL |          NULL |          NULL |              NULL |              NULL |              NULL |  NULL | mysql_lock_tables              | lock.cc              |         332 |
|        7 |  10 | optimizing                     |  0.000022 |  0.000000 |   0.000000 |              NULL |                NULL |         NULL |          NULL |          NULL |              NULL |              NULL |              NULL |  NULL | JOIN::optimize                 | sql_optimizer.cc     |         217 |
|        7 |  11 | statistics                     |  0.000048 |  0.000000 |   0.000000 |              NULL |                NULL |         NULL |          NULL |          NULL |              NULL |              NULL |              NULL |  NULL | JOIN::optimize                 | sql_optimizer.cc     |         429 |
|        7 |  12 | preparing                      |  0.000069 |  0.000000 |   0.000000 |              NULL |                NULL |         NULL |          NULL |          NULL |              NULL |              NULL |              NULL |  NULL | JOIN::optimize                 | sql_optimizer.cc     |         504 |
|        7 |  13 | Creating tmp table             |  0.000221 |  0.000000 |   0.000000 |              NULL |                NULL |         NULL |          NULL |          NULL |              NULL |              NULL |              NULL |  NULL | JOIN::create_intermediate_tabl | sql_executor.cc      |         325 |
|        7 |  14 | executing                      | 12.978405 | 12.953125 |   0.015625 |              NULL |                NULL |         NULL |          NULL |          NULL |              NULL |              NULL |              NULL |  NULL | JOIN::exec                     | sql_executor.cc      |         227 |
|        7 |  15 | end                            |  0.000024 |  0.000000 |   0.000000 |              NULL |                NULL |         NULL |          NULL |          NULL |              NULL |              NULL |              NULL |  NULL | Sql_cmd_dml::execute           | sql_select.cc        |         715 |
|        7 |  16 | query end                      |  0.000007 |  0.000000 |   0.000000 |              NULL |                NULL |         NULL |          NULL |          NULL |              NULL |              NULL |              NULL |  NULL | mysql_execute_command          | sql_parse.cc         |        4547 |
|        7 |  17 | waiting for handler commit     |  0.000313 |  0.000000 |   0.000000 |              NULL |                NULL |         NULL |          NULL |          NULL |              NULL |              NULL |              NULL |  NULL | ha_commit_trans                | handler.cc           |        1570 |
|        7 |  18 | removing tmp table             |  0.000257 |  0.000000 |   0.000000 |              NULL |                NULL |         NULL |          NULL |          NULL |              NULL |              NULL |              NULL |  NULL | free_tmp_table                 | sql_tmp_table.cc     |        2279 |
|        7 |  19 | waiting for handler commit     |  0.000020 |  0.000000 |   0.000000 |              NULL |                NULL |         NULL |          NULL |          NULL |              NULL |              NULL |              NULL |  NULL | free_tmp_table                 | sql_tmp_table.cc     |        2319 |
|        7 |  20 | closing tables                 |  0.000032 |  0.000000 |   0.000000 |              NULL |                NULL |         NULL |          NULL |          NULL |              NULL |              NULL |              NULL |  NULL | mysql_execute_command          | sql_parse.cc         |        4593 |
|        7 |  21 | freeing items                  |  0.000020 |  0.000000 |   0.000000 |              NULL |                NULL |         NULL |          NULL |          NULL |              NULL |              NULL |              NULL |  NULL | mysql_parse                    | sql_parse.cc         |        5264 |
|        7 |  22 | removing tmp table             |  0.000010 |  0.000000 |   0.000000 |              NULL |                NULL |         NULL |          NULL |          NULL |              NULL |              NULL |              NULL |  NULL | free_tmp_table                 | sql_tmp_table.cc     |        2279 |
|        7 |  23 | freeing items                  |  0.000004 |  0.000000 |   0.000000 |              NULL |                NULL |         NULL |          NULL |          NULL |              NULL |              NULL |              NULL |  NULL | free_tmp_table                 | sql_tmp_table.cc     |        2319 |
|        7 |  24 | removing tmp table             |  0.000013 |  0.000000 |   0.000000 |              NULL |                NULL |         NULL |          NULL |          NULL |              NULL |              NULL |              NULL |  NULL | free_tmp_table                 | sql_tmp_table.cc     |        2279 |
|        7 |  25 | freeing items                  |  0.000111 |  0.000000 |   0.000000 |              NULL |                NULL |         NULL |          NULL |          NULL |              NULL |              NULL |              NULL |  NULL | free_tmp_table                 | sql_tmp_table.cc     |        2319 |
|        7 |  26 | logging slow query             |  0.000066 |  0.000000 |   0.000000 |              NULL |                NULL |         NULL |          NULL |          NULL |              NULL |              NULL |              NULL |  NULL | log_slow_do                    | log.cc               |        1623 |
|        7 |  27 | cleaning up                    |  0.000032 |  0.000000 |   0.000000 |              NULL |                NULL |         NULL |          NULL |          NULL |              NULL |              NULL |              NULL |  NULL | dispatch_command               | sql_parse.cc         |        2159 |
+----------+-----+--------------------------------+-----------+-----------+------------+-------------------+---------------------+--------------+---------------+---------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------+--------------------------------+----------------------+-------------+
26 rows in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

Machine B

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROFILING WHERE QUERY_ID=3;
+----------+-----+--------------------------------+----------+----------+------------+-------------------+---------------------+--------------+---------------+---------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------+--------------------------------+----------------------+-------------+
| QUERY_ID | SEQ | STATE                          | DURATION | CPU_USER | CPU_SYSTEM | CONTEXT_VOLUNTARY | CONTEXT_INVOLUNTARY | BLOCK_OPS_IN | BLOCK_OPS_OUT | MESSAGES_SENT | MESSAGES_RECEIVED | PAGE_FAULTS_MAJOR | PAGE_FAULTS_MINOR | SWAPS | SOURCE_FUNCTION                | SOURCE_FILE          | SOURCE_LINE |
+----------+-----+--------------------------------+----------+----------+------------+-------------------+---------------------+--------------+---------------+---------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------+--------------------------------+----------------------+-------------+
|        3 |   2 | starting                       | 0.000082 | 0.000000 |   0.000000 |              NULL |                NULL |         NULL |          NULL |          NULL |              NULL |              NULL |              NULL |  NULL | NULL                           | NULL                 |        NULL |
|        3 |   3 | Executing hook on transaction  | 0.000003 | 0.000000 |   0.000000 |              NULL |                NULL |         NULL |          NULL |          NULL |              NULL |              NULL |              NULL |  NULL | launch_hook_trans_begin        | rpl_handler.cc       |        1119 |
|        3 |   4 | starting                       | 0.000006 | 0.000000 |   0.000000 |              NULL |                NULL |         NULL |          NULL |          NULL |              NULL |              NULL |              NULL |  NULL | launch_hook_trans_begin        | rpl_handler.cc       |        1121 |
|        3 |   5 | checking permissions           | 0.000004 | 0.000000 |   0.000000 |              NULL |                NULL |         NULL |          NULL |          NULL |              NULL |              NULL |              NULL |  NULL | check_access                   | sql_authorization.cc |        2218 |
|        3 |   6 | checking permissions           | 0.000003 | 0.000000 |   0.000000 |              NULL |                NULL |         NULL |          NULL |          NULL |              NULL |              NULL |              NULL |  NULL | check_access                   | sql_authorization.cc |        2218 |
|        3 |   7 | Opening tables                 | 0.000344 | 0.000000 |   0.000000 |              NULL |                NULL |         NULL |          NULL |          NULL |              NULL |              NULL |              NULL |  NULL | open_tables                    | sql_base.cc          |        5574 |
|        3 |   8 | init                           | 0.000007 | 0.000000 |   0.000000 |              NULL |                NULL |         NULL |          NULL |          NULL |              NULL |              NULL |              NULL |  NULL | Sql_cmd_dml::execute           | sql_select.cc        |         666 |
|        3 |   9 | System lock                    | 0.000008 | 0.000000 |   0.000000 |              NULL |                NULL |         NULL |          NULL |          NULL |              NULL |              NULL |              NULL |  NULL | mysql_lock_tables              | lock.cc              |         331 |
|        3 |  10 | optimizing                     | 0.000011 | 0.000000 |   0.000000 |              NULL |                NULL |         NULL |          NULL |          NULL |              NULL |              NULL |              NULL |  NULL | JOIN::optimize                 | sql_optimizer.cc     |         219 |
|        3 |  11 | statistics                     | 0.000020 | 0.000000 |   0.000000 |              NULL |                NULL |         NULL |          NULL |          NULL |              NULL |              NULL |              NULL |  NULL | JOIN::optimize                 | sql_optimizer.cc     |         439 |
|        3 |  12 | preparing                      | 0.000016 | 0.000000 |   0.000000 |              NULL |                NULL |         NULL |          NULL |          NULL |              NULL |              NULL |              NULL |  NULL | JOIN::optimize                 | sql_optimizer.cc     |         520 |
|        3 |  13 | Creating tmp table             | 0.000167 | 0.000000 |   0.000000 |              NULL |                NULL |         NULL |          NULL |          NULL |              NULL |              NULL |              NULL |  NULL | JOIN::create_intermediate_tabl | sql_executor.cc      |         336 |
|        3 |  14 | executing                      | 0.037210 | 0.000000 |   0.031250 |              NULL |                NULL |         NULL |          NULL |          NULL |              NULL |              NULL |              NULL |  NULL | SELECT_LEX_UNIT::ExecuteIterat | sql_union.cc         |        1398 |
|        3 |  15 | end                            | 0.000007 | 0.000000 |   0.000000 |              NULL |                NULL |         NULL |          NULL |          NULL |              NULL |              NULL |              NULL |  NULL | Sql_cmd_dml::execute           | sql_select.cc        |         719 |
|        3 |  16 | query end                      | 0.000002 | 0.000000 |   0.000000 |              NULL |                NULL |         NULL |          NULL |          NULL |              NULL |              NULL |              NULL |  NULL | mysql_execute_command          | sql_parse.cc         |        4579 |
|        3 |  17 | waiting for handler commit     | 0.038665 | 0.000000 |   0.000000 |              NULL |                NULL |         NULL |          NULL |          NULL |              NULL |              NULL |              NULL |  NULL | ha_commit_trans                | handler.cc           |        1569 |
|        3 |  18 | removing tmp table             | 0.000176 | 0.000000 |   0.000000 |              NULL |                NULL |         NULL |          NULL |          NULL |              NULL |              NULL |              NULL |  NULL | free_tmp_table                 | sql_tmp_table.cc     |        2305 |
|        3 |  19 | waiting for handler commit     | 0.000011 | 0.000000 |   0.000000 |              NULL |                NULL |         NULL |          NULL |          NULL |              NULL |              NULL |              NULL |  NULL | free_tmp_table                 | sql_tmp_table.cc     |        2345 |
|        3 |  20 | closing tables                 | 0.000012 | 0.000000 |   0.000000 |              NULL |                NULL |         NULL |          NULL |          NULL |              NULL |              NULL |              NULL |  NULL | mysql_execute_command          | sql_parse.cc         |        4626 |
|        3 |  21 | freeing items                  | 0.000005 | 0.000000 |   0.000000 |              NULL |                NULL |         NULL |          NULL |          NULL |              NULL |              NULL |              NULL |  NULL | mysql_parse                    | sql_parse.cc         |        5299 |
|        3 |  22 | removing tmp table             | 0.000004 | 0.000000 |   0.000000 |              NULL |                NULL |         NULL |          NULL |          NULL |              NULL |              NULL |              NULL |  NULL | free_tmp_table                 | sql_tmp_table.cc     |        2305 |
|        3 |  23 | freeing items                  | 0.000002 | 0.000000 |   0.000000 |              NULL |                NULL |         NULL |          NULL |          NULL |              NULL |              NULL |              NULL |  NULL | free_tmp_table                 | sql_tmp_table.cc     |        2345 |
|        3 |  24 | removing tmp table             | 0.000003 | 0.000000 |   0.000000 |              NULL |                NULL |         NULL |          NULL |          NULL |              NULL |              NULL |              NULL |  NULL | free_tmp_table                 | sql_tmp_table.cc     |        2305 |
|        3 |  25 | freeing items                  | 0.000061 | 0.000000 |   0.000000 |              NULL |                NULL |         NULL |          NULL |          NULL |              NULL |              NULL |              NULL |  NULL | free_tmp_table                 | sql_tmp_table.cc     |        2345 |
|        3 |  26 | cleaning up                    | 0.000015 | 0.000000 |   0.000000 |              NULL |                NULL |         NULL |          NULL |          NULL |              NULL |              NULL |              NULL |  NULL | dispatch_command               | sql_parse.cc         |        2172 |
+----------+-----+--------------------------------+----------+----------+------------+-------------------+---------------------+--------------+---------------+---------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------+--------------------------------+----------------------+-------------+
25 rows in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Your indexing is insufficient. It looks like you have none. Please include `SHOW CREATE TABLE kn_supplier` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE kn_supplier_service`. Check these are the same on both machines. How is `EXPLAIN {query}` different between machines.

Comment: Does `group by a.id` help?

Comment: I have compared, the tables are the same, because they use the same sql to create.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calls to `GROUP_CONCAT` involve every record in the group, with no chance to reduce the overhead there.  In addition, your query has no `WHERE` clause.  You may try adding the following index to the `kn_supplier_service` table:

```
CREATE INDEX idx on kn_supplier_service (supplier_id, branch, type_of_service);
```

This would at least allow MySQL to quickly lookup each `id` value in the `kn_supplier` table against the `kn_supplier_service` table.

Comment: Thx tim, I have to say, yes it works. But but but !!! Why it has such a big difference? You know, the enviroment, the tables, the index, the records are ALL the same! I am totally confused! Machine B does not have such index (supplier_id, branch, type_of_service), but it runs quick! machine A is just a production machine.

Comment: Are you saying that you already had this index defined?  I don't follow your question.

Comment: I just create a new index as your comments, and I find it works

Comment: Regarding understanding why it works, appreciate that with the above index, MySQL just has to scan the `kn_supplier` table once, and then it can use the index for very fast lookup to do the join.  Note that I didn't do anything to improve the `GROUP BY` aggregation portion of the query; that can't be helped much here.

Comment: but the question is why machine B runs so quick without this index(supplier_id, branch, type_of_service) for the same qty records?

Comment: Well the first thing that pops into my head is whether the _data_ on both databases be the same or not?

Comment: the database is the same, MySQL 8.0 with the same schema, all the others are the same, even records in tables. The difference is A is prodcution machine. database maybe a little bit of busy. B is testing machine. Only I use it.

Comment: Then the likely explanation is that the query has nothing to do with it, rather it is other processes on the A server which are causing anything else running on it to slow down.

Comment: is there any tool which I can identify the reason? See, profile cannot help me too much. I can only see the executing consuming is the problem from the profiler results, but I cannot see why.

Comment: I honestly haven't done too much work profiling MySQL instances in production.  For starters, figure out what may be using the database in production.  If you're running things in an environment like AWS, this would be fairly easy to do.

Comment: ，thx anyway...totally have no idea with the enviroment. Maybe some setting is different in my.in.  again, great thx and have a nice weekend.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using MySQL 8.0, I would encourage you to check the output of EXPLAIN ANALYZE (8.0.18) of your query on both systems.

Comment: yes, both are version 8.0.18. One is set to production, the other is set to development. The interesting thing is , the sql runs on production is much slower than on development. Unless I create the index according to Tim's comments. You know, I tried to profile both machines. the results are above. I cannot tell what is exactlly issue from the resuls. @lefred  it seems EXPLAIN ANALYZE is a new fun, let me try